# What's a good way to add a non tex table from external file?

Tags: tables, best-practices, external-files

I'm seeking for your advice and ideas regarding a way to add all my tables in the pdf file as non tex files.
The goal is to make it harder (much harder) for someone to edit the way the tables look in the final pdf file.
At the moment all my tables are separate tex files, and added this way:

```
\begin{table}[tb]
\tabcolsep=0.2cm
\centering
\mycaption{The captio of the table}
\label{tbl:my_table}
\input{some_table}
\end{table}
```

the file some_table.tex will then look like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{2}{c}*{2}{c}@{}}
\toprule
{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{First Cat} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Second Cat} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
{}          & FirstCol  & SecondCol &  FirstCol & SecondCol \\
\midrule
FirstRow    &    0.1    &    0.2    &    0.3    &    0.4 \\
SecondRow   &    0.5    &    0.6    &    0.7    &    0.8 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

One possible option would be to create the files as a standalone pdf file, and add them.

Would like to hear you opinion on that, and possibly better solutions that you can think of.

Comment: do you mean you are distributing tex source but want people not to edit it? Otherwise I do not understand the question, if you only distribute the pdf the layout of the tex source makes no difference.

Comment: If someone has access to the source code, modify a table is really easy, whatever the method you used. If someone has access only to the final PDF always can insert the PDF text as images in a new document and make the table from scratch, not to mention the PDF editors.

Comment: I'm submitting the tex files and a pdf for a paper that going to be published, in this case the publisher is doing some editing. What usually happens is that they edit the tables to be ugly (among other things they do). Then it's a "fight" to make them change it back. So I'm trying to avoid it by making it harder to change the style of the tables

Comment: if you fight the publisher they will not publish, they may even just OCR an image of the table and re-key it in their own format.

Comment: I actually hope to avoid the fight, after they make their changes they send it back for authors final approval.
They do tend to change the style of the tables, but usually will eventually allow the original design if the author insists.
The original submission is created using their template, and following their guidelines.
To avoid their editors changing the style of the tables, I thought to add the tables as pdf files. 
But, wanted to see if anyone has any other suggestions as it will probably take some time to do it properly.